# Can I refer from a UWP project to a .NET Standard project?

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-6.0

I created an UWP app, and a .NET 6.0 project, and added reference of UWP project to the .NET 6 project.

Output of executing proj.bat file that runs this solution executes the following error:.

> Error NU1201: Project MyUWPProject is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Project MyUWPProject supports
> : uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362)

How can fix this? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: The error message is explicit.  Consider targeting .NET Standard 2.0

Comment: The error message shows that the environment of your .NET 6.0 project is .net6.0 and the environment of the UWP project is different, so the current UWP version does not support this. What kind of requirements do you have? Could you be specific? If you want to use UWP API, you can use the WinRT API directly in the console app.

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows that the environment of your .NET 6.0 project is .net6.0 and the environment of the UWP project doesn't support .net6.0. So the UWP project is not compatible with the .NET project.

If you want to use Windows Runtime APIs, you could just make some confirugation in for your .NET 6.0 porject so that you could directly call Windows Runtime APIs in your app. You will need to **Edit Your Project File** and **Modify TargetFramework Element** to `net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0`.

You could check this document - [Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance) for detailed steps.